# 302 error HTPP IIS WINDOWS

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-8

I got 302 error when accessing to my image ( mapper like a virtual directory in    web application from a share server with NTFS restriction ) . I checked the log file of IIS V8 and got this:

IIS LogFiles

```
2018-06-08 14:12:24 10.4.66.38 GET /Images/GetPieceImage id=157416 80 (my domaine)\(my username) 10.16.XX.XX Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysiteweb/ConsoleForceT/GetPieceImageId?PieceId=157416 302 0 0 38
2018-06-08 14:12:24 10.4.66.38 GET /Error/Report/8ZJHAQCH5H_mylogin - 80 PJMS\yfadouchi 10.16.XX.XX Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysiteweb/ConsoleForceT/GetPieceImageId?PieceId=157416 200 0 0 4e }
```

Architecture :

[image: Web Application] 
[image: Authentification for mysiteweb]
[image: Authentification for clintimages]

NB : important information

- The Website use Windows authentication and authorization in ASP.NET
- And when I use the Basic authentication for mysiteweb I get the image but with pupup authentication
- My pool run with a domain user identity with full access to share server to all resource images

Comment: Hi @YCN could you manage to resolve it? If so, it would be great if you could post the solution. I am facing somewhat similar issue at the moment. Your solution might be able to help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that there is no spelling mistake in IIS folder location.
I faced the same issue with one of my Virtual Directories.

Also check the case sensitivity.